# VBA Set Recordet using a variable table name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to access a form's recordset clone from a called function which we're using to essentially dump the data in the recordset into a table we're creating.  I'm trying to call the form from the Forms collection, but I can't figure out how to insert the form name (held in a string passed to the function) into the middle of the set statement.  Here's what it looks like basically:

```
Public Function EditFormData(frmName As String)
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strTableName As String
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim i As Integer

  Set rst = Forms![[[frmName]]].RecordsetClone
```

I'm at a bit of a loss here.  For this particular function, I could pass a recordset to the function, but I have similar quandaries in another place, where passing one isn't an option.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set rst = Forms(frmName).RecordsetClone
```

Comment: +1 I generally use form name, but you can also pass the form itself `EditFormData(frm As Form)`

Comment: Good point.  The set statement would then be: `Set rst = frm.RecordsetClone`

Comment: That's right.  Both work, and I feel like an idiot.  Much appreciated, will mark as answer when it lets me.